# Why is the constant of integration zero when solving the Friedmann equations?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion

I'm confused regarding relating the Hubble constant H$_0$ to current age of the universe $t_0$.

I'm looking at solutions for different epochs of the Friedmann equation, which I've got in the general form
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{\sqrt{\Omega_va^4+\Omega_ca^2+\Omega_ma+\Omega_r}}\frac{\mathrm da}{\mathrm dt}=\mathrm H_0.
\end{align}
Take for instance the radiation-only, $\Omega_r=1$,
\begin{align}
a\frac{\mathrm da}{\mathrm dt}=\mathrm H_0,
\end{align}
if I were coming at this from a more naive perspective, I would take my initial condition to be $a(t_0)=1$,
\begin{align}
\int_1^aa'\mathrm da'=\int_{t_0}^t\mathrm H_0\mathrm dt',
\end{align}
giving
\begin{align}
a(t)=\sqrt{1+2\mathrm H_0(t-t_0)}.
\end{align}
This solve the equation, fits the initial condition, and is unit-less, but differs from the usually stated solution
\begin{align}
a(t)=\sqrt{\frac{t}{t_0}}.
\end{align}
I've figured people arrive at this via some method similar to the following. Either (1), use indefinite integration and take the constant to be zero,
\begin{align}
\int a\mathrm da=\int \mathrm H_0\mathrm dt\\
a=\sqrt{2\mathrm H_0t},
\end{align}
then use the assumption that $a(t_0)=1$ to find a relationship between H$_0$ and $t_0$,
\begin{align}
a(t_0)=1=\sqrt{2\mathrm H_0t_0}\\
2\mathrm H_0=\frac{1}{t_0},
\end{align}
giving the usual solution $a(t)=\sqrt{t/t_0}$.

Or (2), use definite integration and take $a(0)=0$ to get the same result.

What confuses me is that I cannot get H$_0=1/2t_0$ (which reduces the equation I get to the usually stated) using the definition H$_0=\frac{\dot a_0}{a_0}$ or $a(t_0)=1$. I'm not convinced that I should just take the integration constant to be zero, and I'm even more not convinced of using $a(0)=0$, as I believe that solutions are not guaranteed to be unique for $a=0$ given the Picard-Lindelof theorem.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is a deeper question here of how do you even define $t_0$? This is meant to be the age of the universe in a big-bang cosmology model. This time is set by the boundary conditions $a(0)=0$ and $a(t_0)=1$. Not accepting $a(0)=0$ means that you are implicitly rejecting a big-bang singularity, in which case you need to define what you mean by $t=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the confusion is; this seems straightforward.

An arbitrary solution to $a\dot a= H_0$ for constant $H_0$ satisfies
$$
a^2(t_1)-a^2(t_2)=2 H_0 (t_1-t_2)\qquad (\ast)$$
for any $t_1,t_2$. For *fixed* $H_0$, $a^2(t)$ is uniquely specified by the single initial condition at some time $t'$, as 1st-order ODEs usually are. From this you take a square root to obtain $a(t)$, which could get you in trouble if $a(t)$ goes on to change sign, but this is beside the point here.

You could, instead of fixing $H_0$, specify $two$ initial conditions. If these are at times $t_1,t_2$ then clearly
$$H_0=\frac{1}{2(t_1-t_2)} (a^2(t_1)-a^2(t_0))\,.$$
Then specifying the initial conditions
$$
a(0)=0\,,\quad a(t_0)=1
$$
gives $H_0=1/(2t_0)$ and $a^2(t)=t/t_0\implies a(t)=\sqrt{t/t_0}$.